# How do I migrate from Azure to a Windows VPS?

Tags: vps, azure, web-hosting

Basically I’ve been using Microsoft Azure to host my stuff for about a year now. I have a SQL instance and a “free” web site, and more recently, a scheduler to run a program that refreshes the DB daily. This is starting to cost up into $30 a month for these things, and I’m wondering how easy it would be to shuffle my hosting from Azure onto a VPS.

I’m probably going to host it on a service called Winity.io (about $22 a month for a fairly powerful VPS), but I don't know what the most straight forward way to do this would be. I have the original source code and everything on my computer still, so that part is sorted.

Once its on the VPS, what would be the best way to deploy it it as well?  Azure works well with SQL updates and stuff like that… does a similar technology exist in WebDeploy on a VPS host?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what the most straight forward way to do this would be. I
>   have the original source code and everything on my computer still, so
>   that part is sorted.

**Web Contents**

To migrate the web contents, either you can transfer web content through FTP or map your local drives to Remote Desktop connection and copy the content to VPS. Here is a excellent article you wish to refer.

https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/939/How-to-uploadordownload-contents-fromorto-VPSorDedicated-server-via-RDP.html

**Database**

To migrate the database, the best approach would be take the MS SQL database backup through MS SQL Server Management Studio and download it in local system. Create database with the same name and restore database from  previously taken backup at VPS SQL Server.

> Once its on the VPS, what would be the best way to deploy it it as
>   well? Azure works well with SQL updates and stuff like that… does a
>   similar technology exist in WebDeploy on a VPS host?

It depends upon your web host, if you are provided Windows VPS with necessary web deployment tools, you can deploy your websites through web deploy method.